# Robocopy is not copying to the directory I want

Tags: c, robocopy

I am trying to use robocopy to copy my documents into the C:\temp directory. I am using the following code in order to do so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("cd C:\\ && mkdir temp" );
    system("robocopy C:\\Users\\GARcher\\Documents\\ C:\\temp\\ /xjd /e");  
}
```

As you can see, this code attempts to create a temp folder in C:\ if one does not already exist. Following this it utilizes robocopy to copy all folders and subfolder in \Documents across to C:\temp.

Unfortunately, all this code does is copy documents across to C:\Documents and the C:\temp folder disappears when I run it. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you consider that `cd` does not necessarily change the directory in the target drive? Did you try `mkdir C:\temp` without `cd`?

Comment: This fails as described when the actual source directory path name contains an embedded space.  Use "double quotes" around the path to fix.